# Define family of commands via \addtocontents

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I am trying to define a family of commands inside `\tableofcontents`. Here is an example that does not work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\providecommand{\foo1}{0}
\providecommand{\foo2}{0}

\foo1 \foo2

\stepcounter{foo}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newcommand{\detokenize{\foo}\thefoo}{\thepage}}

text

\stepcounter{foo}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newcommand{\detokenize{\foo}\thefoo}{\thepage}}

text
\end{document}
```

This almost works. The command \detokenize produces an extra space at the end. This results in the `.toc` file having something like `\newcommand{\foo 1}{14}` instead of the desired `\newcommand{\foo1}{14}`.

Comment: You are aware that `\newcommand{\foo1}{}` must fail? (or `\providecommand{\foo1}{}` as well!)

Comment: Yes, but this is the type of thing I want to do. I just don't know how to accomplish it.

Comment: @louis: So your interface will necessarily be `\foo1`, `\foo2`, ...? What happens when you want to go past `\foo9`?

Comment: I should have known that everyone would jump at me for expressing a concept with "commands" like `\foo1`. It's pretty trivial to change to roman numerals for the counter or something else like it. As I pointed out in the question, the focus is on the extra space, not the command naming scheme.

Comment: @Werner: Conceptually, to go past `\foo9`, I would go to `\foo10`. Actually, I would use `\fooXXIV` in  place of `\foo24` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, you *cannot* do `\newcommand{\foo1}{whatever}`, nor hope that `\foo1` does something sensible.

Actually, if you do

```
\newcommand{\foo1}{whatever}
```

*after* `\begin{document}` has been processed, there will be no error, but `\foo` will be defined to be equivalent to `\relax`, while `1` and `whatever` will be printed.

If you want to define a family of commands based on a prefix like `\foo` and a serial number, you can define `\foo` as a macro with argument that will do the appropriate action.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{foo#1}{INEXISTENT}{\@nameuse{foo#1}}%
}

\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand{\serialize}{%
  \stepcounter{foo}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \global\protect\@namedef{foo\thefoo}{\thepage}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Here is \verb|\foo{1}|: \foo{1}

Here is \verb|\foo{2}|: \foo{2}

Here is \verb|\foo{3}|: \foo{3}

Some contents

\serialize

\newpage

Some contents

\serialize

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to define a command like `\foo1`, there is not real convenient user interface to access it, since control sequences/commands should contain alphabetic characters only (by default). You would need `\csname foo1\endcsname` or define something like

```
\newcommand{\nameuse}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\let\nameuse\@nameuse% From the LaTeX2e kernel
\makeatother
```

to circumvent it the limitation.

Aside from that, you can define content within the ToC if you `\protect` the commands that should not be expanded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\Alph{foo}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\providecommand{\fooA}{0}
\providecommand{\fooB}{0}

\fooA~\fooB

\makeatletter
\stepcounter{foo}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\global\protect\@namedef{foo\thefoo}{\thepage}}
\makeatother

text

\makeatletter
\stepcounter{foo}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\global\protect\@namedef{foo\thefoo}{\thepage}}
\makeatother

text
\end{document}
```

I've used `\Alph{foo}` to use alphabetic characters in the macro creation.